# syncing a list of already made bullets UNET

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synchronization, unity-networking

I currently have players spawning in with a click to move functionality moving around a space synced perfectly, but I cant get the bullets to sync properly.

When the player spawns in he creates 60 bullets which are then set inactive and stored until an ability is cast, when the ability gets cast I the bullets get sent active and I have a script that syncs them with all the clients as well, but the bullets are only getting set active on the local client, so the SyncPos script doesn't even run.

Do I need to send a message to a separate game object(ie: the net manager) in order to then send a message out to the other clients and say "hey activate this so you can sync it" or is there a better way? and if so how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Do you have a reference to all 60 bullets on each client?

Answer (score 0):

Syncing a game object's active flag over Unet is not supported, because there's no way to find the game object on the other clients since they're inactive. It's like using `GameObject.Find()`; it can't find inactive objects.